# What is the problem with this code?(Python) AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I am working on a discord bot. But I run this error every time. I don't know what is the problem, can you please help me? This is the error:
line 19, in 
@client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Here is the code:

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands




class MyClient(discord.Client):
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?')


# Start

async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged on as', self.user)

# Latency
client = discord.Client()
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')


# 8ball

@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['Biztosan.',         
                 'Nagyon kétséges.']
    await ctx.send(f'Kérdés: {question}\nVálasz: {random.choice(responses)}')

# Clear

@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(f'Kész!')

async def on_message(self, message):
        word_list = ['fasz', 'kurva', 'anyad', 'anyád', 'f a s z', 'seggfej', 'buzi', 'f.a.s.z', 'fa sz', 'k U.rv@ any@dat']

       
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send('Ne használd ezt a szót!')
            
        messageattachments = message.attachments
        if len(messageattachments) > 0:
            for attachment in messageattachments:
                if attachment.filename.endswith(".dll"):
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send("Ne küldj DLL fájlokat!")
                elif attachment.filename.endswith('.exe'):
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send("Ne csak parancsikont küldj!")
                else:
                    break

client = MyClient()
client.run(token)
```

Comment: You have `client = discord.Client()`, but it should be `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?')`.

Comment: it doesn't work what you said

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain it's due to where you're defining your client variable, when I made my discord bot I did it in javascript so I may be wrong but I believe its because you're trying to call a variable that hasn't been defined yet, so move the `client = MyClient()` line up so that its defined as soon as you made the class